# LXD on ZFS on LVM on H/W RAID 10

Tags: raid, lvm, zfs, lxc, lxd

I have a Dell R540 with PERC H730P running RAID 10 over 12 DISK to the tune of ~22TB. I want to run various applications/services in LXD containers.

I understand that ZFS is preferred for LXC storage pools, and that ZFS prefers direct access to raw disks.

My naive approach was to configure Ubuntu with LVM over the H/W RAID, and let LXD init with default settings (ZFS.img on EXT4 on LVM ...). My reading is that this will 'work fine' however isn't optimal performance / protection-wise.

Could someone provide some guidance the various options I have here and which would get the best of most worlds? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to benefit from all ZFS advantages, you need to reinstall the server. Change the HBA configuration from RAID to JBOD (disable RAID). Make sure you can see all disks from the OS. Make sure you can see them as normal disk, not virtual disks exposed by the RAID controller. You should be able to see the hardware details of the disk, like vendor, model, serial number, maybe SMART attributes.

Check the disk sector size if it's 512, 4k or 8k. Create the pool with proper  `ashift` value based on max sector size of the current disks and the disks you intend to add in the pool.